# Converting &#252; to ü

Tags: c#, asp.net, utf-8, datagridview, utf

I am working with asp.net project and i am using datagridview.. so i am filling datagridview and when i read grid view, then some character is changing from "ü" to "`&#252;`"

i am filling datagridview like below :

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
....
..
.

datagridview.DataSource = dt;
datagridview.Databind();
```

when i bind to datagridview..

**datagridview.rows[1][4]** is being **"Türkiye"**

but when i read this value for setting to some textbox.

> txtXXX.Text = datagridview.rows[1][4].Text;

i am getting this value = "T&#252;rkiye" ....

soo my question is : how to i convert "&#252;" to "ü" ?

Answer (score 5):

Hope this helps :

```
System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(datagridview.rows[1][4].Text);
```